# Combine all types in array into a single type

Tags: typescript, types

I have a `superObject()` function which just combined a lot of objects:

```js
type Class<T = any> = {
    new(...args: any[]): T
}

function superObject<C extends Class[]>(...classes: C) {
    let obj = {};
    for(const klass of classes) {
        obj = {
            ...obj,
            ...new klass()
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

There does not seem to be a good way to annotate the return type, as `obj` will have every property of every class. I have tried marking the function as returning `C[number]`, but this gives a union (`classes[0] | classes[1]`, not `classes[0] & classes[1]`). How would I get this type at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a recursive type:

```
type MergeTypes<T extends unknown[]> = 
    T extends [a: infer A, ...rest: infer R] ? A & MergeTypes<R> : {};
```

to merge all of the types in a tuple `T`, then you can:

```
type Class<T = any> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T
}

function superObject<C extends Class[]>(...classes: C): MergeTypes<C> {
  let obj: Partial<MergeTypes<C>> = {};
  for (const klass of classes) {
    obj = {
      ...obj,
      ...new klass()
    }
  }
  return obj as MergeTypes<C>;
}
```

**REVISION**

Upon using the code above, I realize that it's merging the constructor function types, not the types that are constructed. Here's a revised version that extracts the `T` from `Class<T>` and uses that instead.

```
type Class<T = any> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T
}

type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

type MergeTypes<T extends Class[]> =
  T extends [a: Class<infer A>, ...rest: infer R]
  ? R extends Class[]
  ? A & MergeTypes<R>
  : never
  : {};

function superObject<C extends Class[]>(...classes: C): Expand<MergeTypes<C>> {
  let obj: Partial<MergeTypes<C>> = {};
  for (const klass of classes) {
    obj = {
      ...obj,
      ...new klass()
    }
  }
  return obj as Expand<MergeTypes<C>>;
}

class A {
  public foo = 1
}

class B {
  public bar = "monkey"
}

class C {
  public yum = true;
}

const so = superObject(A, B, C)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IDwBUoF4oIHYgB82UA3gFBRR4QDuAFAHTMIBOA5kgFy4EDaAXQCUPdOQC+5cqEhQAogA8w+ACYZiOTBAXAIeFUigBLPADMIrKAHkoAfjJQ+AaWN4oAawggA9qesCeK2cBKHEoHhoANwsAbikZaABZC3YIdHAINC0dPQNYRBRBDUoobN19Qz4EHnhkNBNzSwBBQgAaKGZGVkzgHgaLKAAlARL7QahtcrzawpGqeyaoADIoZI40jLRBwhKIiGjWXbJxOPJTAFc8AGNgI283JHPIVisAIwArCBvUGAmcivydSKTGYVwKSEyNRE8iUqlQa1S6UgaBghGIFCocAgwCg3g+PAACmxbgg4PCUhtkT80SRSCcSqZvJZ6Fd7kgce5wbi-GC6pkhGQSlQ8e9aUKqB1mCLWuKqJ0aLQPOD6EJxZIqOqoN1gOdWG4RbhDIplPpyeskZlqYQ4pJyLyUFBFhioGBzq84EYrlBGd4SABGCRSe2GABCgqorvdnqgrzYJAARABbe6eEDxwN2rm-Z2Rj1ekDnRMkYCsc4QG1Btk4pC+nCPZ5vT43ehNdoh9owVUAei7EqgAD1bJW8DWsYw4N52PQa4wfe0Z7HWPPvIwC4nVUA)

Comment: @Bagel03 I revised my code because it didn't work for your use-case. The revision works nicely.